# How can I specify y-limits in the plots produced by brms::marginal_effects()?

Tags: r, plot, axes, stan

Here's my example code. I'd like to produce several variations of the same plot, so enforcing identical y-limits is important for visual comparison.

```
library(brms)

# data
sgf <- c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10))
Vs  <- c(221, 284, 211, 232, 254, 
         260, 239, 219, 226, 232, 
         388, 399, 421, 419, 332, 
         387, 399, 398, 438, 411)
vspr.df <- data.frame(sgf, Vs)

# perform fit
fit <- brm(formula = Vs ~ sgf,
  data = vspr.df,
  family = lognormal(),
  prior = NULL,
  chains=3,
  iter=300,
  warmup=100)

p <- marginal_effects(fit)
plot(p)
plot(p, ylim=c(0,350))   # no effect
plot(p, ylim=c(0,3500))  # no effect
```

My preferred result is for each of the last 3 lines to result in a plot with different Y limits.

Comment: Find out what the class is for p and then dive into the method for plot on that type of object. Likely when that object is called by plot, the method fixes the ylim, but you can edit the code yourself~

Comment: Thanks @EvanFriedland . 
    > class(p)
    [1] "brmsMarginalEffects"
    > showMethods("plot")
    ...
    x="brmsMarginalEffects", y="missing"
        (inherited from: x="ANY", y="ANY")
    > getMethod(plot,"brmsMarginalEffects")  # error
    > getMethod(plot,list(x="brmsMarginalEffects",y="missing"))  # error
    > getMethod(plot,c("brmsMarginalEffects","missing"))  # error

Clearly missing something here; any help appreciated. :-)

Well, no carriage returns possible in this context but I hope you catch my drift

Comment: You could try using ggplot with the value in `p$sgf`

Answer (score 3):

So `plot(p)` here actually produces a list of `ggplot` objects, as can been seen from looking at the source of `brms:::plot.brmsMarginalEffects`. Also, the help file (`?marginal_effects`) reads:

> *The corresponding plot method returns a named list of ggplot objects, which can be further customized using the ggplot2 package.*

The list items are per effect of interest.

Regardless, we can choose the first element of this list and then use `ylim` from `ggplot` to change the limits:

```
plot(p)[[1]] + ggplot2::ylim(0, 1000)
```

Or use the variable name directly:

```
plot(p)$sgf + ggplot2::ylim(0, 1000)
```

Both give:

[image]

For more control over the axis, use `ggplot2::scale_y_continuous`.